# Rails production error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I have very strange error only in Rails production environment. In development works good. The logs show error in this line in my index.html.erb file.

This is the production log error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person without an ID):
  app/views/seeds/index.html.erb:71:in `block in _app_views_seeds_index_html_erb__4016841983995682700_31529840'
  app/views/seeds/index.html.erb:61:in `each'
  app/views/seeds/index.html.erb:61:in `_app_views_seeds_index_html_erb__4016841983995682700_31529840'
  app/controllers/seeds_controller.rb:17:in `index'
```

The line in my seed index file is this one:

```
<td><%= Person.find(seed.person_id).name %></td>
```

Before this line I query other data in the same way with foreign key and it works. When I check the sql table I see that the Seeds table has the person_id value.

Moreover, when I query the same thing via the rails console in production environment i receive the result without any problems. But when I load the page it shows me "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." and the production.log shows the error above... Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: The particular instance of `seed` in the line above sounds like it's null...  Can you verify it exists?

Comment: Yes it does because when I remove the problematic line with the person everything works. It is a loop <% @seeds.each do |seed| %> and than with the seed variable I access other data that is working...

Comment: And what is `person_id` in this case?  I've generally seen this error when I have something other than an integer or integer as a string, thus Rails doesn't have an ID.

Comment: @CDub the person_id is integer. it exists in the sql table for Seed. So in the console when I do Person.find(Seed.last.person_id).name I receive the name ...

Comment: Okay, so, again, I don't mean to beat a dead horse, but you're *sure* that `Seed.last` and the `seed` in your question are the same?  Now I'm thinking that `seed.person_id` in your question is the FK to a `Person` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys after a whole day of coding by brain was not to good. The point is that in the middle of the table I had a NULL object for person and that was causing the error... Thank you for your time